# Generate numeric id for secondary identifier in django

Tags: django

I want to generate a collision checked, completely unique numeric id for each model. The reason I cannot use auto incrementing id is because I don't want ids to be predictable. I also wanna avoid using UUID, but I am fine with alphanumeric id as well. I am not replacing the primary key, but I am using it get objects in my API

Something like this:

```
8230693489356
```

Or:

```
a435Ga256hb35
```

But not:

```
ab66e4dd-4fee-4fb3-9519-efdc20e5d792
```

This is not a duplicate because:

- The question refered does not solve my problem, it did not solve the askers question either, there is no accepted answer.
- The top answer does not create a collision checked unique id, collisions can happen
- Most of the answers suggest UUID, which is not what I want.
- The question simply asks for a unique id, I am asking for something specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a unique ID in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210458/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-id-in-python)

Comment: @Sebastian Olsen You have find solution ? because i have answer for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wanted to to be unique Id and not just another random id

I've appended the Timestamp and hostname to a randomly generated Integer.
Since you mentioned that it should not be easily guessable I've hashed above String with md5 to generate the final key.

```
import hashlib
import random
import time
import string
import socket
import sys
hostname = socket.gethostname()
def new_id(n):
    return hashlib.md5((str(random.randint(1,sys.maxsize))+hostname+str(time.time()*1000)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:n]

>>> new_id(11)
'8c05917c1c7'
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is collision proof? What if someone posts at the exact same time?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen If someone posts at the same time from the same hostname. you have a random set of alphaNumeric characters. The possiblility of just the random keys is itself extremely unlikely When you combine it with the timestamp and the hostname. It should be pretty unique.

Comment: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: @SebastianOlsen I've updated the code now it works on both python 2.7 and 3

Comment: So what does the `n` argument specify? If it does specify number of characters, that would be great. Having a relatively short but unique identifier is just what I am looking for.

Comment: n is the number of random alphanumeric words passed to the hash function
The size of the output will depend on the hash function being used. 
`sha224` will generate a 56 letter string irrespective of the n parameter. More the value is set to n the more random the hash is going to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109705/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-vishnu667).