# How to create a 8 digit Unique ID in Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, uuid

I am making a web app for practice, it is a job portal. I want to create 8 digit unique IDs for job which will be visible to the end user. Ids can have numbers and alphabets. Pattern needs to be 8 digits without hyphens or dashes like **XXXXXXXX**.

I know there is UUID thing in python. But they seem to generate the id in their specific format. Is there a way to get the id in my required format? If not can someone please guide me on how to go about it?

I know there is a similar thread [How can I generate a unique ID in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210458/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-id-in-python); but it does not answer my question specifically. It did not answer what I was trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shameless plug: use my coupon code generator at https://github.com/scardine/coupon-encode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a unique ID in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210458/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-id-in-python)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well you could use [uuid.hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.hex)

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().hex[:8]  # Might reduce uniqueness because of slicing
```

Or Django also has helper function [get_random_string](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L48) which accepts two parameters `length` *(default=12)* and `allowed_chars`:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
get_random_string(8)
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the uuid4 would only have alphabet characters a-f in it.  Django's helper function would be a better choice.

Comment: Using `.lower()` creates a bias, as now lowercase letters are twice more likely to occur than digits. It would be better to use the `allowed_chars` parameter if you only want lowercase+digits.

Comment: Django helper function did the trick I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @knbk I have removed it now from the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use `os.urandom` for the data, and `base64` encode it;

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: import base64

In [3]: base64.b64encode(os.urandom(6)).decode('ascii')
Out[3]: '6Amtry80'
```

Comment: This solved my use case! Though the Base64 alphabet table contains characters like "+" and "/" which are not safe for use in URLs and file system names, thus I used url-safe versions of the encode/decode functions instead: `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()`  and `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()`. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** use [hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) to convert one-to-one between sequential integers and random-looking strings

If you are creating a web app and need to map string ids like `'x4ua9fam'` to some entry in a database, you want a robust one-to-one method of converting back and forth between an integer and the string id.

Instead of generating a random id each time and checking if it has been taken, you can assign the next available sequential integer `(0, 1, 2, ...)` to each new item and `encode` it into a unique string using [`hashids`](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python). When the user requests the string, you can `decode` it back into the integer and get your data.