# How to generate 4-6 unique numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to generate 4-6 unique numbers in python but when I do `uuid.uuuid4()`, it generates something like `23dfsFe823FKKS023e343431`. Is there a way I can achieve this, generate 4-6 unique numbers like 19391 or 193201.

NB: Beginner with python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703059/how-to-create-a-8-digit-unique-id-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a 8 digit Unique ID in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703059/how-to-create-a-8-digit-unique-id-in-python)

Comment: If you want a decimal number, you can use `random.randint(x, y)` to generate a random integer between x and y.

Comment: Outside of context, unique number does not mean much. The natural sequence 1, 2, 3, etc. gives one unique number on each iteration, and provided you store the last number somewhere you will never get twice the same number. If you want *random* numbers, you must say in which interval and which law (gaussian, uniform, etc.). If you want globally unique numbers, you should make them depend on a hardware id (a MAC address for example), and then the time. I am sorry but your question is not precise enough.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question explaining what you are trying to accomplish and what you mean by unique.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import random

nums = set()
while len(nums) < 4: # change 4 to appropriate number
    nums.add(random.randint(0, 1000000))
```

For example:

```
>>> nums
set([10928, 906930, 617690, 786206])
```

Comment: what is the possibility that it wouldn't repeat itself in a short while

Comment: It’s impossible, the set data structure guarantees that there won’t be repeated values

Answer (score 2):

yes, to make life easy lets use an easy example.

```
#lets import random, to generate random stuff
import random
#create a result string
result = ''
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in range(6):
    result += str(random.choice(nums))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

UUID is for generating Universally Unique Identifiers, which have a particular structure and won't be what you're after.

You can use the `random` module as follows

```py
import random
id = ''.join(str(random.randint(0,10)) for x in range(6))
print(id)
```

What does this do?

- `randint` generates a random number between 0 inclusive and 10 exclusive, i.e. 0-9
- calling this with `for x in range(6)` generates six random digits
- `str` converts the digits to strings
- `''.join` forms a single string from the digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random` from standard python library

random.randint(a, b)
Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

```
In [1]: from random import randint                                                             

In [2]: randint(1_000, 999_999)                                                                
Out[2]: 587848

In [3]: randint(1_000, 999_999)                                                                
Out[3]: 316441
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate N number of a random number or token by specifying a length of Token this will be an easy and feasible solution.

```
import random

#num[]: by the combination of this, a random number or token will be generated.
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] 

#all the tokens or random number will be stored in a set called tokens.
#here, we are using a set, because the set will never contain duplicate values.
tokens = set()

result='' #to store temporaray values

while len(tokens) < 10000: # change 10000 to the appropriate number to define the numbers of the random numbers you want to generate.
    #change 6 to appropiate number to defined the length of the random number.  
    for i in range(6):
        result+=str(random.choice(nums))
        tokens.add(result)
        result=''


print(tokens)
#print(len(tokens))
#print(type(tokens))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use uuid to generate number then you can code something like this

```
digit = 5   # digits in number 

import uuid
for i in range(6):
  print(uuid.uuid4().int[:digit])
```

Or

```
from uuid import uuid4
result = [ uuid4().int[:5] for  i in range(6) ]
```

Comment: This is not possible since `int` is not subscriptable