# How to distinguish two different calls to the same Flask webhook?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, webhooks

I am using Heroku platform to put simple webhook, which is written on python and uses Flask. Cloud system I use sends POST request to my webhook, sending me some data and I should respond.

I would like to keep a log of all requests and responses.
Sometimes it happens, that Cloud system may send the same requests to my webhook again (for whatever reason - I didn't send a response in specified time or something like that).

I would like to distinguish such request. If I simply put information into the log about what I get it may happen that I  will see in my log something like:

1) Starting processing request (1st request)

2) Starting processing request (2nd request)

3) Calculating response (1st request)

4) Calculating response (2nd response)

I would like to put some unique identifier to each line, something like session id, to filter all entries that belong to the same process.

How is this possible?

Here is the sample code:

```
# import of necessary modules
import modules

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_json('config.json')


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    body = request.data
    signature = request.headers['x-pyrus-sig']
    secret = str.encode(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

    if _is_signature_correct(body, secret, signature):
        return _prepare_response(body.decode('utf-8'))


def _is_signature_correct(message, secret, signature):
    ...
    # Verifying that request is from trusted source

def _prepare_response(body):
    ...
    # Sending the response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that instead of trying to find a unique session id from the system, it's better to generate your own.

Something like this:
[How can I generate a unique ID in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210458/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-id-in-python)